# Decode functions comparison of expression and search

Tags: sql, oracle

If I give `decode(1,2,3,4,5)` it just display null value I know it is because no expression in matched with search value so default value is returned.But I want a explanation about how it is matched.And also if I give same function `decode(a,b,c,d,e)` it returns invalid identifier e,why?

Comment: @Rahul [ORACLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) at a guess.

Comment: @Phylogenesis, has to be since there is no `Decode` in wither `MySQL` or `SQL Server`

Comment: @ rahul,yes it is oracle

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you just need to put your character data into quotes:

```
select decode('a','b','c','d','e') from dual
```

But you asked for an explanation of how it is matched so here from the [Oracle docs on DECODE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm)

> If expr and search are character data, then Oracle compares them using nonpadded comparison semantics. expr, search, and result can be any of the datatypes CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, or NVARCHAR2. The string returned is of VARCHAR2 datatype and is in the same character set as the first result parameter.
>
> If the first search-result pair are numeric, then Oracle compares all search-result expressions and the first expr to determine the argument with the highest numeric precedence, implicitly converts the remaining arguments to that datatype, and returns that datatype.

EDIT:  "I want to know the reason why it specifically says e is invalid integer and not the other characters."

It is returning the error on the last result expression, not just the e. So if you stop at c or go to g you get whatever is last. My best guess is it just reporting the last error..possibly because of the way it the engine is parsing, Might find the "last" error first and report it.

In fact you see the same thing with

```
select a,b,c from dual
```

so nothing to do with decode.

Comment: @ karl I know that when I give within quotes it will take it as character and prints default value null.But I want to know the reason why it specifically says e is invalid integer and not the other characters

Comment: Oracle's SQL*Plus only returns one compile error. And whether it it parses bottom up and returns the first error it hits, or whether it parse top down and returns the last error hit I do not know. But if you put the e in quotes you will get the same error for the d and so on until you fix it all

Comment: Then why it returns null value when I give decode(1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: It returns null when the is no match and no default specified, but a valid syntax. That is basically the second the sentence from the Oracle doc link I included.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments Senthil, clearly it is the mechanics of DECODE that you are unclear on. I will try to explain.

The first element in the list is the value that you want to match. After that, we deal in pairs of elements where if you match to the first item in the pair, the returned value from decode is the second item in the pair. You can have as many pairs to match to as you want. And finally you can optionally add a default return value if no match is found.

```
So DECODE(a,b,c,d,e) means
Evaluate a. 
If a = b, return c
If a = d, return e.

So DECODE(1,2,3,4,5) is saying
Evaluate 1
 If 1=2, return 3
 If 1=4, return 5
```

Since 1 is not equal to 2 or 4, you get a null return.

If you added a final default return value, you would get that

```
  DECODE(1,2,3,4,5,6)
Evaluate 1
 If 1=2, return 3
 If 1=4, return 5
 If no matches found, return 6.
```

This is why I tend to format my calls to DECODE to clearly show the pairs. I would write it as:

```
Select
DECODE( field_x
         ,matchvalue1, return1
         ,matchvalue2, return2
         ...
         ,matchvalueN, returnN
         <,default_Value_if_appropriate>)
...
```